# importing same module more than once

Tags: python, import, import-hooks

So after a few hours, I discovered the cause of a bug in my application. My app's source is structured like:

```
main/
    __init__.py
    folderA/
        __init__.py
        fileA.py
        fileB.py
```

Really, there are about 50 more files. But that's not the point. In `main/__init__.py`, I have this code: `from folderA.fileA import *`

in `folderA/__init__.py` I have this code:

```
sys.path.append(pathToFolderA)
```

in `folderA/fileB.py` I have this code:

```
from fileA import *
```

The problem is that fileA gets imported twice. However, I only want to import it once.

The obvious way to fix this (to me atleast) is to change certain paths from `path` to `folderA.path`

But I feel like Python should not even have this error in the first place. What other workarounds are there that don't require each file to know its absolute location?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't modify sys.path this way, as it provides two ways (names) to access your modules, leading to your problem.

Use absolute or [unambiguous-relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) instead.  (The ambiguous-relative imports can be used as a last resort with older Python versions.)

#### folderA/fileB.py

```
from main.folderA.fileA import *   # absolute
from .fileA import *               # unambiguous-relative
from fileA import *                # ambiguous-relative
```

Of course, you should be using specific names in place of that star.

Answer (score 5):

- Modifying `sys.path` isn't something you do in a real program. It hurts modularity and portability with no gain over setting PYTHONPATH permanently or putting your module in a place Python can find it.
- Never ever ever ever use `import *`. It pollutes your namespace and makes your code unpredictable.
- You don't want folderA on `sys.path`. It is a subpackage of `main` and should always be treated as such. Always use absolute imports going to top-level packages: `import main.folderA` rather than `import folderA` or anything else; it will make your code a lot easier to follow and move around and install.